# Online quiz with radio buttons having same name

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm making a simple Quiz using Js, the problem is that my **inner loop** (i.e `i`) is not works as expected.

I have taken 3 questions and each question has 3 radio options, options of each question have same name. all the options of fist question have `name='cap'`,  options of second question `name='an'` and third question is `name='lang'`.

My js function is as follows:

```
function my(){
  var count=0; 
  var totalQuestions = 3;
  var correctAnswers = 0;
  var alertText;
  var n=["cap","an","lang"];
  var j,i;
  for(j=0; j<n.length; ++j){
    var x = document.getElementsByName('n[j]');
    for(i = 0; i < x.length; ++i){
      if (x[i].checked){
        if (x[i].value == 'true'){
          count=count+10;
          correctAnswers++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(correctAnswers == totalQuestions){
    alertText = "Congratulations! You got all the questions right!";
  }
  else {
    alertText = "You got " + correctAnswers + " correct answers and score is " + count;
  }
  alert(alertText);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace line

```
var x = document.getElementsByName('n[j]');
```

to

```
var x = document.getElementsByName(n[j]);
```

That's problem because for js `getElementsByName('n[y]')` means "get elements with name `n[y]`", but not item of list `n`, which contain name of elements you need to select.

**Good Luck !**

Comment: Thank you. Can please tell me whether the line: for(i = 0; i < x.length; ++i)  is correct ? will x.length will give number of options ?

Comment: @Shivi12 yes it sould give you number of options

Answer (score 2):

`var x = document.getElementsByName('n[j]');`

Should be

`var x = document.getElementsByName(n[j])`

`getElementsByName` returns all elements that match the name per [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp).

The issue is you hardcoded the string `'n[j]'` so its looking for all elements with the name `'n[j]'`.

You actually want to look up the name from y our array `n` at index `j` So removing the quotes will actually evaluate that expression `n[j]`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from

```
var x = document.getElementsByName('n[j]');
```

To

```
var x = document.getElementsByName(n[j]);
```

Your existing code tries to find a element which has `name='n[j]'`ie: a string. But what you want is to evaluate the expression `get the element  with the name equal to evaluated value`.